# Is there a static way to get current request/context in Go?

Tags: go

I want my logging methods to output some sort of request ID. To do that I need to pass a request object (or some derivative) to the logging functions.

This is all fine when logging from the request handlers, but is problematic when used from within library-style methods, as I don't wish those to be aware of any ongoing http-requests.
Furthermore, those same library methods might be used in the future by console applications, and than the request-id would be replaced by some sort of worker-thread-id.

Using a context solves the problem, but this means I will have to add a context parameter to all my methods, which is somewhat annoying.

So, basically, what I need is some sort of static storage that is passed between method and goroutine calls.

I'm not sure there's anything like that in Go, so maybe my approach is totally off-base, in that case, I would be happy to hear what is a better approach to solve the above problem.

Thanks,

Comment: "So, basically, what I need is some sort of static storage that is passed between method and goroutine calls." There is no such thing and the Go authors dislike things like goroutine ids or storage. "I would be happy to hear what is a better approach to solve the above problem." --> "Using a context solves the problem, but this means I will have to add a context parameter to all my methods". You solved the problem. "... which is somewhat annoying" if you feel so, than you will have to do something annoying. You'll mange.

Comment: It looks to me as bad taste when all methods within a solution contain the same parameter.   
It adds complexity by creating the question of "Does this method need a context?" whenever writing a new method, while the need for a context might be 3 method-calls deeper than the method being written.

Yes, if that's the only option, I would use a context, or alternatively get rid of the request-id in logs, but before doing that, I'd rather see if there's a better option.

Comment: What's bad taste to you is considered best practice by others (see, e.g. https://blog.golang.org/context#TOC_5.). There is no sensible way to argue about taste, especially in programming.

Comment: Looks so... oh well, time to do a re-write :/

Comment: @Svarog "Does this method need a context?" If the library wants to log the request ID, then it _needs_ some kind of context. By passing a `Context`, you make that explicit. If you don't pass a context explicitly, there is still an _invisible_ context, and Go doesn't like hidden, invisible things. Go likes being explicit, Go likes not doing much in the background hidden from your eyes.

Comment: This becomes especially painful when html/template rendering is involved because the "template" form within the template language does not (easily) allow multiple parameters, and there is no efficient form of dependency injection without re-parsing templates with a stateful FuncMap.

Answer (score 0):

Try another logging library. For instance, in log15 (https://github.com/inconshreveable/log15) a Logger as an embedded key/value context.

```
logger := log.New("request_id", "8379870928")
```

You can pass the logger object to anyone that needs to log. Later on:

```
logger.Warn("blabalbla")
```

... will embed the request_id that you have put.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but you can do something similar logrus, and it doesn't really help - still requires an object to be passed among all functions. I'd rather have it be a context object to comply to convention.